# Why a part of this expression, similar to another, is left unchanged?

Tags: replacement

An expression has one of its part replaceable and one, strictly similar, that isn't. Please, can you point at the difference ? I can't pinpoint the complication ...

The FullForm of `rN` is:

```
Plus[
  Power[Subscript[u, x], 2],
  Power[Subscript[v,x],2],
  Times[
    m,
    Plus[
      Times[2, Subscript[u, x],Subscript[u,y]],
      Times[2, Subscript[v, x], Subscript[v, y]]
     ]
   ],
  Times[Power[m, 2], Plus[Power[Subscript[u, y], 2], Power[Subscript[v, y], 2]]]
 ]
```

and here I post the substition as image, for reader's comfort:

[image]

Comment: A simpler example is `a + b + c + d /. {a + b -> 1, c + d -> 2}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation for [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html):

> ReplaceAll looks at each part of expr, tries all the rules on it, and
>   then goes on to the next part of expr. The first rule that applies to
>   a particular part is used; no further rules are tried on that part,
>   **or on any of its subparts.**

What happens in your example is that the first rule matches the *whole* expression (because `Plus` has the `Flat` attribute) and then no further rules are tried on the subparts.

The same will happen with any Flat function:

```
SetAttributes[f, Flat];

f[a, b, c, d] /. {f[a, b] -> 1, f[c, d] -> 2}
(* f[1, c, d] *)
```

To work around this you can use `ReplaceAll` repeatedly or use `ReplaceRepeated`

```
f[a, b, c, d] /. {f[a, b] -> 1} /. {f[c, d] -> 2}
(* f[1, 2] *)

f[a, b, c, d] //. {f[a, b] -> 1, f[c, d] -> 2}
(* f[1, 2] *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It clarifies all. By the way, in akin circunstancs will come in handy the D. Bailey's free package ColourMaths, even though it seems intended for step by step calculations, instead of automatic processing. Does anyone know about any comparable gadget ? ColourMaths is extrelemy useful, but is about ten year old and presumably more packages have been developed meantime ...